# Removing text between Strings using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

So I already went through a couple of the similiar questions but I couldn't get anything to work.

I am currently trying to use this:

```
sed -i '/^<script/,/script>/{/^<script/!{/script>/!d}}' file.txt
```

Which I thought would delete everything between `<script` and `script>` but as you might have guessed it doesn't do so.

this is the code that is in the txt file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 bla bla some script bla bla
</script>
```

There are multiple scripts at various places in the **.txt** and it is supposed to delete every single one of them.

Comment: What is the significance of the [tag:gitlab] tag on this question? Are you processing XML documents? What do the documents look like? Do you just wish to delete the `script` nodes and their contents unconditionally?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Kusalananda I am using sed in the gitlabci.yml.

Comment: So it's not an XML file?

Comment: @Kusalananda No it is not

Comment: (1) During testing, you should always drop the `-i` option. You can debug more easily and avoid messing up your file. (2) Your script looks good and removes the `bla` line in your example here, which is what you want, I suppose. What is your `sed` version?

Comment: It may not be XML, but it is HTML, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the text between opening and closing `script` tags where the opening one is always at the start of a line, all you need is:

```
sed -i '/^<script/,/<\/script>/d' file
```

Of course, using `sed` for things like this [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936) and you should use a proper parser instead. For instance, what if your input file contains nested blocks?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 bla bla some script bla bla
<script>
    foo
</script>
</script>
```

But whether or not that is an issue will depend on your input data.

Comment: That Stackoverflow post was really interesting thank you very much. How would I do that if the script wasn´t at the beginning of the line? E.g. seperated by whitespace?

Also what would you use instead of sed?

Comment: @SirHawrk it depends on the input file. If you're parsing a structured language like XML or HTML, use a dedicated parser for it. Other people have already done the work for you, and almost certainly better than you or I would do it, so don't reinvent the wheel. For the simple case you show, if it can have whitespace before it (but nothing else), you could try `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*<script/,/<\/script>/d' file`.

Comment: @SirHawrk to give you an idea, [this is the sort of level of regex expertise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1081936) you need to write your own parser.